# CQWP slots are not displaying

Tags: content-query-web-part, item-styles

I wrote this code in itemstyle.xsl

```
    <xsl:variable name="AssistPrinEmail">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(@AssistantPrincipal1Email,',')" />
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="AssistPrinEmail2">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(@AssistantPrincipal2Email,',')" />
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="AssistPrinEmail3">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(@AssistantPrincipal3Email,',')" />
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="AssistPrinEmail4">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(@AssistantPrincipal4Email,',')" />
    </xsl:variable>
```

I would think that four slots would appear in a CQWP using that style.  They would be AssistantPrincipal1Email, AssistantPrincipal2Email, AssistantPrincipal3Email, and AssistantPrincipal4Email.  This is not the case.  The slots are not appearing in the toolbar.

Any idea why these slots are not displaying?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try:

```
<xsl:variable name="AssistPrinEmail" select="@AssistantPrincipal1Email"/>
```

To make sure the slots are working without the 'substring-after' selection?

Comment: I tried that.  What I eventually did was add the fields to the CommonViewFields section in the webpart xsl.  That forced the fields to work.  They still didn't appear as slots but at least the content worked.  You shouldn't HAVE to do that, but CQWP and slots are buggy/broken in SP2010.  I hope things get better with SP1.

Comment: You also have to declare slots as variables at the FIRST level of the template, that's where the CQWP slots parser is expecting them. I know this is late to the party, but this works fine in SP1.